# Delphi convert from c#

Tags: c#, delphi

i really need your help to port this c# code to Delphi one :

```
public unsafe byte[] Encode(byte[] inputPcmSamples, int sampleLength, out int encodedLength)
        {
            if (disposed)
                throw new ObjectDisposedException("OpusEncoder");

            int frames = FrameCount(inputPcmSamples);
            IntPtr encodedPtr;
            byte[] encoded =new byte [MaxDataBytes];
            int length = 0;
           /* How this can be ported to delphi */
            fixed (byte* benc = encoded)
            {
                encodedPtr = new IntPtr((void*)benc);
                length = API.opus_encode(_encoder, inputPcmSamples, frames, encodedPtr, sampleLength);
            }
            encodedLength = length;
            if (length < 0)
                throw new Exception("Encoding failed - " + ((Errors)length).ToString());

            return encoded;
        }
```

The main code part that i'm looking for is :

```
fixed (byte* benc = encoded)
                {
                    encodedPtr = new IntPtr((void*)benc);
                    /* API.opus_encode = is declared in an other Class */ 
                    length = API.opus_encode(_encoder, inputPcmSamples, frames, encodedPtr, sampleLength);
                }
```

many thanks

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: @David Heffernan so many thanks , my question is how could i port that part into delphi .

Comment: What part are you struggling with? Do you understand the C# code? Do you know what's behind `API.opus_encode` because clearly none of us do? Please work harder to provide context. Please make it very clear what you have tried so far, and how it failed.

Comment: `fixed (byte* benc = encoded)` pins `encoded` to get its address. Pinning is not needed in Delphi. `encodedPtr = new IntPtr((void*)benc);` is almost a no-op. It casts a `byte*` to `void*` and then to `IntPtr`. You may be looking for the Delphi `Pointer` type. So I believe you're just looking for something like `encodedPtr := @encoded;` (disclaimer: I didn't touch Delphi for *years* now)

Comment: @David Heffernan : yes i know what's behind the " API.opus_encode " just how this can be ported to delphi : fixed (byte* benc = encoded)
                {
                    encodedPtr = new IntPtr((void*)benc);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to know how to deal with the `fixed` block in the C#.

```
byte[] encoded =new byte [MaxDataBytes];
....
fixed (byte* benc = encoded)
{
    encodedPtr = new IntPtr((void*)benc);
    length = API.opus_encode(_encoder, inputPcmSamples, frames, encodedPtr, sampleLength);
}
```

This use of `fixed` is to pin the managed array to obtain a pointer to be passed to the unmanaged code.

In Delphi we just want an array of bytes, and a pointer to that array. That would look like this:

```
var
  encoded: TBytes;
....
SetLength(encoded, MaxDataBytes);
....
length := opus_encode(..., Pointer(encoded), ...);
```

or perhaps:

```
length := opus_encode(..., PByte(encoded), ...);
```

or perhaps:

```
length := opus_encode(..., @encoded[0], ...);
```

depending on how you declared the imported function `opus_encode` and your preferences.

If `MaxDataBytes` was a small enough value for the buffer to live on the stack, and `MaxDataBytes` was known at compile time, then a fixed length array could be used.